# A point is translated along the surface of a unit sphere. How do I determine the new spherical coordinates of the point?

Tags: geometry, spheres, programming, spherical-trigonometry

A point on a unit sphere at ($\theta$ = 0, $\psi$ = $\pi$/2) moves over the surface on great circle by $\alpha$ radians at an angle $\gamma$ from "north" (the north pole being at $\psi$ = 0). How would I calculate the new spherical coordinates for the point using $\alpha$ and $\gamma$?

[Diagram of the question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vupk.png)

For context, I am programming a simple game that takes place on a sphere.

Comment: I think I found the solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234631/find-the-final-latitude-longitude-after-a-movement-on-the-globe

Comment: By "translated" you mean "rotated"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to also state the extra  $\phi \text{ or } \psi$ you want to shift it to. If new $(\theta, \phi)$ are given in same coordinates, then,

$$ (x,y,z)= 1 {(\cos (\theta+ Delta;  \theta),
\sin (\theta+ \Delta \;\theta), \sin (\phi+ Delta \;\phi)}$$

Comment: The new $\theta$ and $\phi$ are not known. The question is asking how I can calculate these values based on the movement described by $\gamma$ and $\alpha$. Are you saying that this isn't possible given the information provided?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in spherical trigonometry.

Form a triangle with vertex $A$ at $\theta=0,\psi=\pi/2$, $N$at the North pole $\psi=0$, and $B$ at your unknown point which I label $\theta=y,\psi=x$.

We apply the Law of Cosines for Arcs. In this relation note that $AN$ measures $\pi/2$, so its cosine is $0$ and its sine is $1$. Thus we have a simplified form:

$\cos x = \sin\alpha\cos\gamma$

This has a unique root for $x$.

Next apply the Law of Sines:

$\sin y =\sin\alpha\sin\gamma/\sin x$

where division by zero is avoided everywhere except the poles. This gives two roots in the domain $0\le y<2\pi$, so you must choose. To do so note that $y$ will be an increasing function of $\alpha$ and that the two quantities must become equal at every multiple of $\pi/2$ (why the latter?).